# Jmeter wamp-protocol integration

Tags: jmeter, load-testing, wamp-protocol, crossbar

Here is the story:
we have several servers connected to wamp (crossbar.io)
I am creating load tests for part of this system and need a way to get info from wamp server to Jmeter.

So far I found only WS plugin for Jmeter, but it wont work with wamp.
Any bright ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Clearly wamp is a whole new protocol and JMeter doesn't support it out-of-the-box. Thankfully you can extend JMeter quite easily. If there are java or java family language bindings for your protocol system, you can use [beanshell sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_Sampler) (relatively less performant) or groovy through [JSR223 sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) (better performance)

If you feel like it, you can always write up your [own Wamp sampler as well](https://jmeter.apache.org/extending/jmeter_tutorial.pdf).